# Can't findIndex property or method in IE11 throwing an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Having an issue with `findIndex()` property on IE11, can't seems to replicate the error in Chrome.

Better way of achieving similar result as below without `findIndex` so IE11 won't complain.

```
var index = basketArray.findIndex(function(item) {  
  return item.skuField === basketObj.skuField;
});

if (index > -1) {
    basketArray[index].qtyField = basketArray[index].qtyField + 1;
} else {
    basketArray.push(basketObj);
}
return basketArray;
```

Comment: Use [findIndex Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?v=control#Polyfill)

Comment: Not all browsers support newer methods added in ES6

Comment: Spoke too soon, thanks found an answer now. Shame, ES6 is nice and it looks much easier to read.